# How to set CKAN on the network

Tags: ckan

I am currently working on a project and I was assigned to set CKAN on the network (it currently is working on localhost, but we want to make it accessible from outside).
What configurations should I change in CKAN files and in the infrastructure?
We have here a team responsible for the network and servers. Should I only ask them for a IP address and a port to set CKAN and change the `ckan.site_url` to that IP:port or is it more complex? I am kinda lost here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you ask your network admins for an IP address and a corresponding domain name, such as opendata.mycompany.com. Mounting CKAN at the root of a domain is simpler than mounting it on a sub-path e.g. mycompany.com/opendata

You should set it up so that you access CKAN at the same address whether you're inside or outside the company's network. If you have to use different addresses, because you can only set ckan.site_url to one of those. If it is set to a address that is not accessible in both, you'll find obscure things don't work properly, such as the links embedded in CKAN's Atom feed.